# Calculadora em php

Tags: php

Como eu faço uma calculadora em php?
Eu fiz o código mas não exibe resultado.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang = "pt-br">
    <head>
        <title> Exemplo</title>
        <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action=calculadora.php" method="get" >
            Primeiro Numero: <input name="num1" type="text" />
            Segundo numero: <input name="num2" type="text" /> 
            Operacao (quatro operações):  <input name="operacao" type="text" /> 
            <input type="submit" value="Calcular" />     
    </form> 
    <?php
        $a = $_GET "num1";
        $b = $_GET "num2";
        $op =$_GET "operacao";
        $c = []
        if($op == "soma")
            $c = $a + $b;
            //echo $c = "resultado";
        else if($op == "subtracao")
            $c = $a - $b;
            //echo $c = "resultado";
        else if($op == "multiplicacao")
            $c = $a*$b;
            //echo $c = "resultado";
        else
            $c = $a/$b;
         echo "O resultado da operação é: $c";
    ?>      
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9):

Segue o código ajustado conforme sugestão do @perdeu, mas usando método POST e botões.
Procurei manter a simplicidade do original, acrescentando alguns pequenos detalhes para ilustrar o uso do *value* do *submit*, e mais alguma sutilezas.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang = "pt-br">
<head>
   <title>Exemplo</title>
   <meta charset = "UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
   <form action="" method="post" >
      Primeiro Numero: <input name="num1" type="text"><br>
      Segundo numero: <input name="num2" type="text"><br>
      <input type="submit" name="operacao" value="+">     
      <input type="submit" name="operacao" value="-">     
      <input type="submit" name="operacao" value="*">     
      <input type="submit" name="operacao" value="/">     
   </form> 
<?php

   $a = $_POST['num1'];
   $b = $_POST['num2'];
   $op= $_POST['operacao'];

   if( !empty($op) ) {
      if($op == '+')
         $c = $a + $b;
      else if($op == '-')
         $c = $a - $b;
      else if($op == '*')
         $c = $a*$b;
      else
         $c = $a/$b;

      echo "O resultado da opera&ccedil;&atilde;o &eacute;: $c";
   }

?>       
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Para acessar valores de um formulário utilize a sintaxe a baixo.

```
   $a = $_GET['nome_do_campo_html']
```

e não

```
 $a = $_GET "num1";
```

Answer (score 3):

É possível fazer isso com apenas uma linha:

```
echo call_user_func(['+' => 'bcadd', '-' => 'bcsub', '*' => 'bcmul', '/' => 'bcdiv'][$_POST['operacao']] ?? 'bcadd', $_POST['num1'], $_POST['num2'], 2);
```

Você pode usar o BCMath em combinação com `call_user_func`, que poderá chama-lo, o BCMath possui maior precisão para multiplicações.

O `call_user_func` permite chamar qualquer função por meio do nome. Isto pode ser perigoso caso permita o usuário informar qualquer valor, porque consequentemente o usuário também poderá chamar qualquer função do PHP. Neste caso, existe uma array que define quais funções estão autorizadas a serem usadas, e usará o `bcadd` por padrão caso um outro valor seja enviado.

---

Para ficar um pouco mais fácil de entender:

```
<?php

// Definimos os valores padrões do POST:
$_POST = array_replace(['op' => '+', 'a' => 0, 'b' => 0], $_POST);

// Definimos as operações suportadas e sua função no BCMath:
$ops = ['+' => 'bcadd', '-' => 'bcsub', '*' => 'bcmul', '/' => 'bcdiv', '**' => 'bcpow', '%' => 'bcmod'];

// Encontramos a função baseado na entrada do usuário. Caso não for suportado a operação, etnão o `+` será usado como padrão:
$op = $ops[$_POST['op']] ?? $ops['+'];   

// Fazemos chamamos a função usando os valores de A e B:
$resultado = call_user_func($op, $_POST['a'], $_POST['b'], 2);

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="pt-br">
<form action="#" method="post">
    <br>A: <input name="a" type="number" step="any"
                  value="<?= htmlentities($_POST['a'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8') ?>">
    <br>B: <input name="b" type="number" step="any"
                  value="<?= htmlentities($_POST['b'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8') ?>">
    <br><?php
    foreach ($ops as $n => $_) {
        echo '<input type="submit" name="op" value="' . $n . '">';
    }
    ?>
    <br> Resultado: <input readonly value="<?= $resultado ?>">
</form>
</html>
```

---

Answer (score 1):

**1º- Utilizaremos um FORM (HTML)**

```
<!-- Método: $_POST | Action em branco porque executaremos na própria página -->
        <form method="post" action="">
            <!-- Input que receberá o primeiro valor a ser calculado -->
            <input type="text" name="v1" placeholder="Valor 1" />

            <!-- Select com o tipo de operação (Somar, Diminuir, Multiplicar ou Dividir -->
            <select name="operacao">
                <option value="soma">+</option>
                <option value="subtrai">-</option>
                <option value="multiplica">*</option>
                <option value="divide">/</option>
            </select>

            <!-- Input que receberá o segundo valor a ser calculado -->
            <input type="text" name="v2" placeholder="Valor 2" />

            <!-- Input que enviará os valores para a função de cálculo -->
            <input type="submit" name="doCalc" value="Calcular" />
        </form>
```

**2º- O arquivo .PHP com a função de cálculo**

```
<?php
        # classe :: Calculadora
        class Calculadora {

            # Função "Calcular" para executar o cálculo dos valores (v1 e v2)
            public function Calcular() {

                # Se for setado algum valor ào submit (doCalc), executa a operação
                if (isset($_POST['doCalc'])) {

                    # Se a operação for soma (value = soma), então...
                    if ($_POST['operacao'] == "soma") {

                        # Armazena a soma de [v1 + v2] na variável $resultado
                        $resultado = $_POST['v1'] + $_POST['v2'];

                        # Exibe a variável $resultado com os valores já somados
                        return $resultado;

                        # Ou então, se a operação não for (value = soma), e sim (value = subtrai) então...
                    } elseif ($_POST['operacao'] == "subtrai") {
                        $resultado = $_POST['v1'] - $_POST['v2'];
                        return $resultado;
                    } elseif ($_POST['operacao'] == 'multiplica') {
                        $resultado = $_POST['v1'] * $_POST['v2'];
                        return $resultado;
                    } elseif ($_POST['operacao'] == 'divide') {
                        $resultado = $_POST['v1'] / $_POST['v2'];
                        return $resultado;
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        # Instancia a classe CALCULADORA()
        $calcular = new Calculadora();

        # Executa a função
        echo $calcular->Calcular();
        ?>
```

Sei que tem maneiras mais curtas e objetivas de fazer, mas esta é uma das mais simples.

Comment: Você poderia incluir a explicação da sua resposta? Da maneira como está, ficou 100% dependente de sites externos. Se eles cairem, adeus resposta.

Comment: O mesmo foi editado para análise.

Comment: Acredito que seja melhor passar os valores como argumento para `calcular()` pq não é bom utilizar variáveis globais($_POST/$_GET) diretamente num método.