# Fazer cálculos de valores externos ($_GET)

Tags: php, get, matemática

Boa tarde, sou novo em php, e estou fazendo alguns exercicios, mas não estou conseguindo fazer um exercicio que pedem para fazer soma, divisão,multiplicação ou subtracção dependendo dos valores inseridos em $_GET, mas usando o elseif? Deixo uma imagem do exercicio, pois são dois pontos, a primeira parte já fiz, a segunda não estou a perceber como fazer!
[image: Print screen dos dois exercicios.]

Comment: Por favor edite sua questão incluíndo o código que você já desenvolveu para a questão 1 para que possamos te auxiliar.

Comment: Assim vc como manda os números, vai mandar o operador pela url($_GET) e aplicar a operação correta. ex: `if($operacao == '+'){ echo $a + $b;}`, **lembre** de tratar a divisão por zero.

Comment: Relacionado/quase duplicata: [Calculadora em php](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11824/91)

Answer (score -1):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma.

Exercicio 1

```
$num1 = $_GET['num1'];
$num2 = $_GET['num2'];

if(($num1 != null) AND ($num2 != null)){

   $result = $num1 + $num2;
   echo "o resulto da soma dos números é: $result";

}else{
   echo "Os valores não foram informados, por favor tente novamente.";
}
```