# Como retornar um resultado válido a partir de uma operação em PHP?

Tags: php, operadores

Olá.

Quero retornar o resultado de uma operação utilizando como parâmetro dois números e o operador. Acontece que o meu resultado é uma string.

```
<?php
$n1 = $_POST['n1']; //primeiro número
$n2 = $_POST['n2']; //segundo número
$operador = $_POST['operador']; // +-*/

$resultado = fazConta($n1,$n2,$operador);
echo $resultado;

function fazConta($n1,$n2,$operador){

    $x = $n1.$operador.$n2; 
    return $x;

}
?>
```

No exemplo acima, ele retorna a operação e não o resultado. Exemplo: "3+2" e não "5".

Comment: Relacionada[Calculadora em php](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11824/91). Da pra fazer o `eval()` ex: `$op = '+';
eval("echo 30 $op 5;");` mas de uma lida antes em   [Eval é mocinho ou bandido?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/128845/91)

Comment: Nem teria como retornar `5`, pois o `.` é o operador de concatenação de strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não pode usar operadores como variáveis porque os operadores são construtores. Não pode ser passado como string ou objeto nem nada disso. Um único meio **viável** seria o uso do `eval()`. Um meio "inteligente" e mais consistente é criar uma função para cada operador. `soma()` `subtrai()` `multiplica()`, `divide()`. Assim fica mais organizado e não precisa misturar regras específicas de uma operação com outra.

Vou deixar mais claro um exemplo, a operação de divisão provoca erro quando tenta dividir por zero.

Mas isso não ocorre quando multiplica, subtrai ou soma.

Então, ao escrever uma função genérica para englobar esses quatro operadores, teria que criar condicionais para verificar quando está tentando dividir e cuidar o valor zero.

```
function carculadera($operador, $n1, $n2) {
    switch($operador) {
        case '+':
            return $n1 + $n2;
        break;
        case '-':
            return $n1 - $n2;
        break;
        case '/':
            if ($n1 != 0 && $n2 != 0) {
                return $n1 / $n2;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        break;
        case '*':
            return $n1 * $n2;
        break;
    }
}
```